# Header,Footer being displayed on just last page using itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, header, itext, footer

I have tried all the solutions and came up with no answer and Finally that lead me to the decision that to post my own question and to have an answer.Well this shows the header only on the top of the page and leaves the other pages blank. I tried the following code:

```
public void WriteDocument()
{
    RichTextBox rtbnew = new RichTextBox();

    //rtbnew.Rtf = this.rtb.Rtf;
    //String _rtfTohtml = this.markupConverter.ConvertRtfToHtml(rtbnew.Rtf);
    //MessageBox.Show(_rtfTohtml);
    rtbnew.Text = this.rtb.Text;
    string str = rtbnew.Text;
    TextReader tr = new StringReader(str);

    //Declare a itextSharp document 
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 16, 16, 16, 16);

    //Create our file stream and bind the writer to the document and the stream 
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@path + "/Doc2.pdf", FileMode.Create));

    events = new PDFGeneration.Events();

    //Open the document for writing 

    document.Open();
    events.OnEndPage(writer, document);
    events.onOpenDocument(writer, document);
    events.setHeader("Urdu Word Processor");
    //Add a new page 
    document.NewPage();
    events.OnStartPage(writer, document);
    //events.onEndPage(writer,document);
    //Reference a Unicode font to be sure that the symbols are present. 
    BaseFont bfArialUniCode = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"fonts\\adobe-arabic-regular-1.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    //Create a font from the base font

    iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfArialUniCode, 16.0f);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(tr.ReadToEnd(), new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfArialUniCode, 12.0f));

    //Use a table so that we can set the text direction 
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    //Ensure that wrapping is on, otherwise Right to Left text will not display 
    table.DefaultCell.NoWrap = false;
    table.SplitRows = true;
    table.SplitLate = true;
    //Create a regex expression to detect hebrew or arabic code points 
    const string regex_match_arabic_hebrew = @"[\u0600-\u06FF,\u0590-\u05FF]+";

    if (Regex.IsMatch(rtbnew.Text, regex_match_arabic_hebrew, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        table.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
    }

    //Create a cell and add text to it 
    PdfPCell text = new PdfPCell(p);
    //Ensure that wrapping is on, otherwise Right to Left text will not display 
    text.NoWrap = false;

    text.SetLeading(5.0f, 1.0f);// line spacing

    text.Padding = 1.0f;
    text.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.TOP_BORDER;
    text.UseBorderPadding = true;
    text.BorderWidthTop = 5.0f;
    //text.BorderColorTop = BaseColor.GRAY;
    //text.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
    text.ArabicOptions = ColumnText.DIGITS_EN2AN;
    table.SplitRows = true; // waits for the rows to get fit in a page and as it exceeds page height, forward text to next page.
                            //Add the cell to the table 
    table.AddCell(text);

    //Add the table to the document 
    document.Add(table);

    //Close the document 

    events.onCloseDocument(writer, document);
    document.Close();

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@path + "/Doc2.pdf");
    //Launch the document if you have a file association set for PDF's 
}
```

And for Events I used:

```
public override void OnStartPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
{
    // TopNosh Header logo:
    PdfPTable tableTitle = new PdfPTable(1);
    string path = @"C:\Users\M.Shahid.Sultan\Pictures";

    iTextSharp.text.Image imgLogo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(path + "//header.png");
    imgLogo.Alignment = 6; // iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_RIGHT;
    imgLogo.ScalePercent(80f); // change it's size

    Chunk chnk = new Chunk(imgLogo, 0, -10);
    PdfPCell imgTag = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(chnk));
    imgTag.Colspan = 2;
    imgTag.Border = 0;
    imgTag.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
    tableTitle.AddCell(imgTag);
    document.Add(tableTitle);
}

public override void OnEndPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
{
    PdfPTable tablefooter = new PdfPTable(1);
    tablefooter.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
    float[] widthfooter = new float[] { 1f };
    tablefooter.SetWidths(widthfooter);

    tablefooter.SpacingBefore = 100f;

    PdfPCell headerfooter = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("© Copyright 2010                            " + "Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + "                            " + "Page: " + writer.PageNumber, new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
    headerfooter.HorizontalAlignment = 0; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
    headerfooter.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.TOP_BORDER;
    tablefooter.AddCell(headerfooter);
    document.Add(tablefooter);
}
```

Now, this code snippets is showing the header only on first page and not on others. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use page events, register your page event listener with the pdf writer instead of calling the event methods yourself. Don't use onStartPage to add any contents to the page.  In OnEndPsge don't use document.Add but instead the direct content. Have a look at [this sample](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=103)

Comment: I did the same as you mentioned but in resulting pdf, i get first page which is empty one and all the content goes to second page. Plus i am getting double headers being printed at top of the page. Please help!

Comment: *I did the same as you mentioned* - no. At least in the code in your question you do the opposite. Take this as a sample: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=103

Comment: Infact, i have changed my code a bit and got a single header at first page finally. Though i 'd tried the code you pointed from the book and got no better results. Now situation is, i have single table to which i am throwing contents. So when text gets larger in size, most probably, table gets splitted in multiple pages which i reckon that it is showing header at first page because i have just one table?

Comment: This link helped me alot: [link](http://www.developerbarn.com/community/entries/using-itextsharp-to-generate-pdf-with-header-and-footer.30/)

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in the comments and edits. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Infact, I have changed my code a bit and got a single header at first page finally. Though I'd tried the code you pointed from the book and got no better results. Now the situation is, I have single table to which I am throwing contents. So when text gets larger in size, most probably, table gets split into multiple pages which I reckon that it is showing header at first page because I have just one table?
>
> This link helped me alot: [link](http://www.developerbarn.com/community/entries/using-itextsharp-to-generate-pdf-with-header-and-footer.30/)
>
> Well I have changed my code a bit as:

```
PdfPTable footerTbl = new PdfPTable(1);

        //set the width of the table to be the same as the document
        footerTbl.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width;

        //Center the table on the page
        footerTbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;

        //Create a paragraph that contains the footer text
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph(String.Format("Urdu Word Processor                 Date : {0:dd/MMM/yyyy}                  Page Number : {1}", DateTime.Now, writer.PageNumber), footer);

        //add a carriage return
        //para.Add(Environment.NewLine);
        //para.Add("Some more footer text");

        //create a cell instance to hold the text
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(para);

        //set cell border to 0
        cell.Border = 0;

        //add some padding to bring away from the edge
        cell.PaddingLeft = 120.0f;

        //add cell to table
        footerTbl.AddCell(cell);

        //create new instance of Paragraph for 2nd cell text
        //para = new Paragraph("Some text for the second cell", footer);

        //create new instance of cell to hold the text
        //cell = new PdfPCell(para);

        //align the text to the right of the cell
        //cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
        //set border to 0
        //cell.Border = 0;

        // add some padding to take away from the edge of the page
        //cell.PaddingRight = 5;

        //add the cell to the table
        //footerTbl.AddCell(cell);

        //write the rows out to the PDF output stream.
        footerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, (document.BottomMargin + 790), writer.DirectContent);
```

> And edited this my main class:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

        //Create our file stream and bind the writer to the document and the stream 
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@path + "/Doc2.pdf", FileMode.Create));

        **events = new PDFGeneration.Events();
        writer.PageEvent = new PDFGeneration.Events();**
        //Open the document for writing 

        document.Open();
```

> Finally **SOLVED!** Thank you everyone!